# How to merge coverage reports?

Tags: gcc, gcov, lcov, gcovr

I have a C program which I compile with -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage flags.Then I run the program on 5 different inputs, this will override the .gcda file and give me a combined report.But I want to have the coverage report of individual tests and store them in a folder and when I run any coverage tool on this folder I get report for each test as well as a combined report.Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `gcovr` and `lcov` can merge coverage data from multiple runs, but gcov has no built-in functionality.

Gcovr 5.0 added the `-a/--add-tracefile` option which can be used to [merge multiple coverage runs](https://gcovr.com/en/5.0/guide.html#combining-tracefiles). After each test, use gcovr to create a JSON report. Afterwards, you can use `gcovr -a cov1.json -a cov2.json`  to merge multiple coverage data sets and generate a report in the format of your choosing. You can add as many input JSON files as you want, and use a glob pattern (like `gcovr -a 'coverage-*.json'`) if you have many files.

You can also consider whether using the `lcov` tool with its `--add-tracefile` option would work: You can run lcov after each test to generate an lcov-tracefile (which you can turn into a HTML report with genhtml). Afterwards, you can merge the tracefiles into a combined report. It is not possible to use lcov's tracefiles with gcovr.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with lcov and it works but what if I have hundreds of test cases then I need to add each tracefile individually and that is not convenient. I was thinking whether I should use some tools like TestWell CTC++  or RapiCover.

Comment: @Vatsal Re “I need to add each tracefile individually”: you can write a script to run the tests and add the tracefiles. Re “whether I should use some tools”: open source tools like lcov, gcov, and gcovr are mostly developed by hobbyists in their free time. Due to this lack of development resources they can be quite limited. (Disclosure: I am the gcovr maintainer.) It is very well possible that paid tools offer more convenient features, but I'm not familiar with them and suspect they can get rather expensive.

Comment: thank you for your help @amon.I'll write the scripts to run tests and add the trace files as it seems a convenient and cheap option. And thanks for maintaining  gcovr its a great tool.

Comment: "gcov has no built-in functionality" - I believe this is no longer true, please see another answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add to another answer, `gcov` can also merge coverage data from multiple runs with the help of `gcov-tool`:

```
$ gcov-tool merge dir1 dir2
```

(by default results will be stored into `merged_profile` folder).

Unfortunately `gcov-tool` allows merging only two profiles at a time but you can use [gcov-tool-many](https://github.com/yugr/maintainer-scripts/blob/master/gcov-tool-many) to work around this.